# How to dump json dictionary into multiple file given condition

Tags: python, json, dictionary, logging, user-input

I am trying to create a separate json file for each student from a user input.

At the moment, I can only dump all information into one file but I need the dictionary to be in a separate file according to the name from the user input.

I am also trying to update a dictionary every time the user input

```
import json

def get_input():
#user input to record in log
    name = input("Name:")
    d = {} #my dictionary
    d['date'] = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format:')
    d['hours'] = input("Hours:")
    return(name,d)

out = {}

while True:
    exit = input('Do you want to add another input (y/n)?')
if exit.lower() == 'n':
    break
else:
    name, d = get_input()
    out[name] = d

#dump into separate file according to name from user input
if name == 'Jessica':
    with open('jessica.json','a') as j:
       json.dump(out, j, indent= 2)
elif: name == 'Wendy':
    with open('wendy.json','a') as w:
       json.dump(out, w, indent= 2)
else:
    with open('tat.json','a') as t:
       json.dump(out, t, indent= 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code is that every time the value of variable name is overwrite with the last name that was input. try save json file for each iteration of input. but change the name of dictionary because in every iteration the content has acumulated.

```
import json

def get_input():
#user input to record in log
    name = input("Name:")
    d = {} #my dictionary
    d['date'] = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format:')
    d['hours'] = input("Hours:")
    return name,d

out = {}

name=''
d=''
while True:
    exit = input('Do you want to add another input (y/n)?')
    print(exit)
    if exit.lower()=='n':
        break
    else:
        name, d = get_input()
        out[name] = d
        with open(name + '.json','a') as j:
            json.dump(out, j, indent= 2)
        out={}
#dump into separate file according to name from user input

if name == 'Jessica':

    with open('jessica.json','a') as j:
       json.dump(out, j, indent= 2)

else:
    if name == 'Wendy':
        with open('wendy.json','a') as w:
            json.dump(out, w, indent= 2)
    else:
        with open('tat.json','a') as t:
            json.dump(out, t, indent= 2)
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a new json file for each person, and that person has its own corresponding dictionary.

One solution would be to create a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
out = {
    'jessica':{'date': x, 'hours': y},
    'wendy':{'date': x2, 'hours': y2}
}
```

And then loop over the *out* dictionary.

```
for name, dictionary in out.items():
    with open(name,'a') as j:
       json.dump(dictionary , j, indent= 2)
```